# No data to display in PCM Backoffice Data Quality Coverage

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

In hybris 1811 PCM backoffice > Dashboard > I am just getting No data to display under Data quality coverage. Is there any additional configuration required to enable this.

[image]

Comment: That is Data Quality Widget. You can verify configuration again & share details here. https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/5bf1e5f262a7445384ae4891ed5c8d28.html

Comment: Hi issue still exists after following below steps.

1. Added below code in pcmbackoffice-backoffice-config.xml under pcmbackoffice-summary-view component.

<summary-view:section name="QualityGroup">
             <summary-view:data-quality-group warning="0.8" error="0.2" label="dataQualityGroupLabel" domain-id="default"/>
         </summary-view:section>

2. Did ant all
3. System update by selecting update running system and pcmbackoffice extension
4. Added productmanagergroup for admin user
5. I noticed core and marketing attributes drop down is missing under Data Quality Coverage.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My issue belonged with pcmbackofficesamplesaddon. This is all useful links that I found.

Data Quality
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/5bf1e5f262a7445384ae4891ed5c8d28.html

Summary View Widget
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/73c72587ab0a4898bfed2cda081569c7.html

Coverage Calculation Framework
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8b948fed8669101480f78e638bbdb940.html

Widgets
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/633a1253bf3844eea4ac13f681c198da.html

Solr Facet Chart Widget
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/10a8658247a442fdb4bbab7b6002e244.html

Solr search in BO
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/05b4bb74ef014575b98d3addc37634cb.html?q=solr%20facet%20chart

pcmbackofficesamplesaddon
https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/f021529d51c743d8a8c57a4680d4a586.html?q=pcmbackofficesamplesaddon

--

1. add extensions (pcmbackofficesamplesaddon, addonsupport) to localextensions.xml
2. do ant clean all
3. do system update extensions
4. go to BO archestrator and do reset all
5. go to BO and do synchronization for BO product cockpit (after that you should check your solr for new core or cores (BO products)
6. if you still have no data quality in BO productcockpit than go to
   hybris/bin/modules/backoffice-addons/pcmbackofficesamplesaddon and search for an impex files
   (common-addon-extra, common-addon-extra_en) and try to import them manually or check if data from those files was imported successful. Run BO products indexation again.